# How many digits does a Uint type is?

Tags: solidity

I know that a Uint is the same type of a Uint256 and both size is 256 bits, but how many number digits accept without launch an overflow in a smart contract ejecution?

Answer (score 4):

I did this simple test over Remix IDE avoiding declaration errors. I think is not exactly and depends of the digit number and position, but maybe helps you.

```
//UINT digits
uint8   myUint8     = 123; //3
uint16  myUint16    = 12345; //5
uint32  myUint32    = 1234567890; //10
uint64  myUint64    = 12345678901234567890; //20
uint128 myUint128   = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789; //39
uint256 myUint256   = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567; //77
```

Comment: The largest uint with N bits is `2^N - 1` it has `1 + trunc(N * log_10(2))` decimal digits, so with N bits you can fully represent integers with `trunc(N * log_10(2))` decimal digits. I think this formula matches your findings +/- 1.